# Need a way to space a vertical li without spacing the corresponding border

Tags: html, css, border

what im trying to do is have a vertical list with a solid border on the left side, but with 1 or 2 px space between each li. I can't use margin-bottom because then the border would break. I'm ultimately trying to have a list with a solid color on it's left side(no spaces), and when i hover the individual li for it to actually go left, over the existing border.I'm not set about using borders, but i've tried to do it with a wrapper div and i just can't seem to get it right, so any suggestions are welcome :)Oh and the vertical list is gonna be changing in height, so just putting a div as a background without having the height to auto to the list element is a no go.Heres the working link http://jsfiddle.net/hDHDF/ and i  have the following code

```
<div id="menu">
<ul class="menu">
<li class="openmaincategory"><span><a href="#">###</a></span></li>
<ul class="categories">
<li class="subcategory"><span><a href="#">###</a></span></li>
<li class="subcategory"><span><a href="#">###</a></span></li>
<li class="subcategory"><span><a href="#">###</a></span></li>
</ul>
<li class="maincategory"><span><a href="#">###</a></span></li>

</ul>
</div>
```

and the corresponding css:

```css
#menu{
    position:absolute;
    right:0px;
    left:0px;
    top:120px;
    height:auto;
    width:190px;
    margin-top: 35px;
    margin-left:67px;
}
.menu {
    list-style-type:none;
    padding-right:10px;
    color:#6c6762;
}

.maincategory{
    background-color:#ada397;
    height:40px;
}
.openmaincategory{
    height:40px;
    background-color:#ada397;
}

.menu li a{
    display:inline-block;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}

.menu li{
    border-left:solid #6c6762 40px;
}

.menu li:hover{
    border-left:solid #6c6762 20px;
    padding-left:10px;
}

.menu span a{
    color:#5b5856;
    font-size:20px;
    padding-left:4px;
    padding-top:6px;
}

.menu a{
    text-transform:none;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#6c6762;
}

.subcategory {
    background-color:#d7d1c9;
    height:40px;
}
```

Comment: Would you like to move this to http://jsfiddle.net to see a working example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by adding the border to the list itself and making the hover effect margin-left:-20px.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to use padding rather than margin. I set up an example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/hQbRK/3/) based on your code.

Key parts are moving the subcategory class to the span from the li and adding the .last so you can play around with final spacing.

```
.categories li span{
    background-color:#d7d1c9;
    height:40px;
    padding-top:2px;
}

.subcategory .last{
    padding-bottom:2px;
}
```

Update with the padding for the anchor on the last li.

Comment: Your solution indeed does not break the border, but it messes an awful lot with the li and the hover border itself. Even in your example the 3 buttons affected dont look proper. Thanks, though, i ll try to mess around with it a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Have the border on the list itself, not on the list items.

Comment: If i have the border on the list itself, hover doesn't work as it's supposed to.